# How to convert ECW to PNG with gdal_translate while preserving colors

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, ecw

I am trying to convert some ECW files to PNG using the command `gdal_translate test.ecw -of png test.png`, but the PNG file comes out grayscale.

How do I produce a colored PNG from an ECW file using this tool?

Output from `gdalinfo test.ecw`:

```
Driver: ECW/ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x)
Files: test.ecw
Size is 16000, 24000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 32N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",9,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",25832]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (448000.000000000000000,6283000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.125000000000000,-0.125000000000000)
Metadata:
  COLORSPACE=MULTIBAND
  COMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET=4
  VERSION=2
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  448000.000, 6283000.000) (  8d 9' 3.88"E, 56d41'17.50"N)
Lower Left  (  448000.000, 6280000.000) (  8d 9' 6.06"E, 56d39'40.48"N)
Upper Right (  450000.000, 6283000.000) (  8d11' 1.41"E, 56d41'18.29"N)
Lower Right (  450000.000, 6280000.000) (  8d11' 3.51"E, 56d39'41.27"N)
Center      (  449000.000, 6281500.000) (  8d10' 3.71"E, 56d40'29.39"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Band #0
  Overviews: 8000x12000, 4000x6000, 2000x3000, 1000x1500, 500x750, 250x375
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Band #1
  Overviews: 8000x12000, 4000x6000, 2000x3000, 1000x1500, 500x750, 250x375
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Band #2
  Overviews: 8000x12000, 4000x6000, 2000x3000, 1000x1500, 500x750, 250x375
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Band #3
  Overviews: 8000x12000, 4000x6000, 2000x3000, 1000x1500, 500x750, 250x375
Band 5 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Band #4
  Overviews: 8000x12000, 4000x6000, 2000x3000, 1000x1500, 500x750, 250x375
```

Comment: What happens if you translate to JPEG2000 instead?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I've done that now

Comment: @wingnut gdal_translate tells me that the JPEG2000 driver is deprecated. If I suppress the message, I get "0ERROR 1: Unable to write scanline 0 of the component 0."

Comment: Add gdalinfo report about the source image. Why do you want to create output as PNG? It is very bad GIS format for big images.

Comment: @user30184 Done. Because I need to use the images in some software that only support PNG.

Comment: You may suggest the developer of the software to add support for more GIS-friendly formats like tiled GeoTIFF. Your image has a size of 16000 by 24000 pixels and the software must always open the whole PNG image even if it would only need a small subset.

Comment: Your image has 5 channels and png format does not support that. Just to make sure that the the input image is generally OK try `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate test.ecw test.tif`. If is ok have a new try with png format by selecting three bands for RGB with the `-b ` parameters.